# Excel - Getting Names in a chart

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need to get a chart like this, where the green cells contain the list of names from the column and row headers, without duplicates:

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/acv1c6wu1/chart_3.jpg]

Could You please help me to figure out the formulas that I need to use in order to produce such a chart?

Comment: You'd need to be a bit more descriptive than that...

Comment: Look up 'concatenate'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ex:
B4 cell expression `=IF(B$3=$A4,B$3,B$3&" "&+$A4)`

B4 copy to range of B4::E7

**Short description**:

**& Operator**:

& Operator to concatenate strings.

E.g.

"ABC" & "DEF" -->result: "ABCDEF"

**FUNCTION IF()**:

IF(condition expression, result of true case expression, result of false case expression)

**Relative reference formula**:

Address of the cell is changed according to the amount that has moved when copying the formula.

E.g.
case B3 copy to right cell: B3 change to C3

case B3 copy to down cell: B3 change to B4

**Absolute reference formula**:

It is possible to suppress a change in address by copying by adding a `$` portion of the row and column addresses to copy the formula.

E.g.
case $B3 copy to right cell: B3 change to B3

case $B3 copy to down cell: B3 change to B4

case B$3 copy to right cell: B3 change to C3

case B$3 copy to down cell: B3 change to B3

case B$3 copy to down and right cell : B3 change to C3

case $B$3 copy to down and right cell : B3 (N/C)

Comment: Friend, could You explain me the formula (=IF(B$3=$A4,B$3,B$3&" "&+$A4)) in more detail? You are really good at excel,btw!